# CoreBluetooth setNotifyValue invalid parameters

Tags: ios, macos, core-bluetooth

I'm trying to get notifications from my iOS app to my Mac app using CoreBluetooth, but I'm getting this error in the `peripheral:didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic:` method on the Central side: `Error Domain=CBErrorDomain Code=1 "One or more parameters were invalid." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=One or more parameters were invalid.}`.

The peripheral app initializes the onlineUUID characteristic with property Notify and permission for Reading.

```
func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService service: CBService, error: NSError?) {
    for characteristic in service.characteristics! {
        if characteristic.UUID.isEqual(self.onlineUUID) {
            print("Found online characteristic") // this prints
            print("Properties are \(characteristic.properties.rawValue)") // 16==Notify
            peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, forCharacteristic: characteristic)
        }
    }
}
```

This looks like the online tutorials, but it's not working. I've restarted both apps, cleaned the project and restarted Xcode. Using Xcode 7.2 and Swift 2.1.1 on iOS 9.2 and OS X 10.11.2. Quite confused; please help.

Comment: Check this out tutorial might can help you, I've done exactly for my health device and worked. this might will help to your example - http://www.raywenderlich.com/52080/introduction-core-bluetooth-building-heart-rate-monitor

Comment: Are you cleared through self.onlineUUID in if condition?

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue can be sorted out if you just add a self inside the function:

```
self.sensorPeripheral.setNotifyValue(true, forCharacteristic: thisCharacteristic)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for everyone's time; this exact code worked when I restarted bluetooth on the peripheral. It was registering the characteristic, but setNotifyValue() caused this unusual error message until I restarted bluetooth.

I discovered that the code worked by swapping which device was the peripheral and which was the central.